# How to re-initialize ckeditor after destroy without page reload

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

How can i re initailize ckeditor (4) after destroying the instances so i dont have to reload the page.  Im destroying them to clean up the inline divs before saving (see my comments on why) the content to mysql via ajax

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Massive inline editing &mdash; CKEditor Sample</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script>
    // The "instanceCreated" event is fired for every editor instance created.
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(event) {
      var editor = event.editor,
        element = editor.element;
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- START CONTAINER DIV -->
  <div id="container">

    <div id="headerLeft" contenteditable="true">
      <!-- START HEADERLEFT DIV -->
      <h2 id="sampleTitle">
        CKEditor<br> Goes Inline!
      </h2>
      <h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet dolor duis blandit vestibulum faucibus a, tortor.
      </h3>
    </div>
    <!-- END headerLeft DIV -->

    <div id="headerRight" contenteditable="true">
      <!-- START HEADERRIGHT DIV -->

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies.
      </p>
      <p>Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada
        fames ac.
      </p>


    </div>
    <!-- END headerRight DIV -->
  </div>
  <!-- END CONTAINER DIV -->
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>

  <input type="button" id="clickME" value="Save Changes">

  <script>
    $("#clickME").click(function() {

      //START FOR STATEMENT 
      // Cleaning up the div's that contain contenteditable="true" because ckeditor is changing them form
      // <div id="headerRight" contenteditable="true">  TO
      // <div id="headerLeft" contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative; " role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, headerLeft" title="Rich Text Editor, headerLeft" aria-describedby="cke_53">
      // Without this for statement

      // IS THERE AN ALTERNATIVE TO PREVENT DESTROYING CKEDITOR INSTANCES????

      for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy()
      }
      // END FOR STATEMENT

      // GET CONTENTS FROM CONTAINER DIV
      var htmlStr = $('#container').html();

      // CALL FUNCTION TO SAVE CONTENT FROM CONTAINER DIV VIA AJAX
      addHit(htmlStr);


      // HOW TO RE INITIALIZE CKEDITOR HERE SO CKEDITOR WORKS AGAIN?????

    });

    // START FUNCTION TO SAVE DATA VIA AJAX
    function addHit(data1) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/save.php",
        data: "var1=" + data1,
        success: function(msg) {
          alert("Data Saved: " + msg); //Anything you want
        }
      });
    }
    // END FUNCTION TO SAVE DATA VIA AJAX
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store in your database values of editors, not entire `#container` element. And voila! - no need to destroy editors, simpler code, better UX.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the data and then save. This will save you the pain of meddling with CKeditor. Do something like this

```
var data_to_save = $("<div>", {id: 'headerLeft', contenteditable: 'true'}).append("<original div>").children().clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check a live example in my following fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/samuelj90/0hx0bnk9/2/

```
var editorInstance;
document.getElementById('toogleEditor').addEventListener('click',function() {
  if (CKEDITOR) {
    if (editorInstance) {
        editorInstance.destroy();
      editorInstance = undefined;
    } else {
      editorInstance = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
      editorInstance.setData("MY HTML DATA");
    }
  }
})
```